# Minecraft resource pack sounds not working

Tags: audio, minecraft

I'm trying to add music into my Minecraft resource pack (replace sounds), but when I'll play the sound, nothing plays (other sounds works by default resource pack)

Comment: I don't think this question belongs here.  Also you have not shown any effort, examples, or a good explanation for your question.  Your question is very broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, I tried audacity to convert to .ogg and that worked.